# RSA encryption using OAEP with SHA256 hash algorithm in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encryption, rsa, sha256

I want to use `RSA` encryption with `SHA256` padding but as I found that `RSACryptoServiceProvider` doesn't support `OaepSHA256` as padding and some users suggest to use `RSACng` which is a new implementation of the `RSA` algorithm to support more things like `SHA256` as padding.

The problem is here that I got this error while initiating `RSACng` (and I guess unity doesn't implement `RSACng` yet): `NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.`

Initiation code: `rsa = new RSACng();`

- Is there anything wrong with my codes or knowledge?
- Is there any other way to use `RSACng` in Unity3D?
- Is there any other way to use SHA256 as padding for RSA encryption in Unity3D?

Ps. I want to use `RSA` encryption for server/client communication on UDP connection. As I know `SHA1` and `PKCS1` (which supported by `RSACryptoServiceProvider`) are not secure and fast enough for `RSA` padding.

Comment: *As I know SHA1 ... are not secure and fast enough for RSA padding*. SHA1 is secure enough when used in the hash functions in the OAEP padding scheme. Still, it is wise to avoid SHA1 for any security function to help remove it from the ecosystem. But if you can't avoid it then it's safe to use in OAEP.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Sorry, I read this section of document wrong (read "may not" as "may"!):
"although the collision
resistance of SHA-1 has succumbed to a series recent attacks, such as [WYY05], the security of
RSA-OAEP instantiated with SHA-1 may not be correspondingly affected as a consequence." Ref : https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/223.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  "President James K. Polk" comment I realized that although the collision
resistance of SHA-1 (as mentioned in https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/223.pdf), it's secure to use as `OAEP` in `RSA`.

But now I'm interested in my other questions about using `SHA256` as `OAEP` in `Unity3D`.